# How color keys with showkeys with non-gray color?

Tags: color, showkeys

Nowhere have I been able to see an example of using a color other than a shade of gray to color the labels revealed in LaTeX by `\usepackage{showkeys}`.

For example, suppose I want `label`s to be revealed in a (light) green and the `ref`s to those labels to be labeled in a (light) red or, better yet, a (light) pink. How does one do this?

I'm well aware that `\usepackage{show keys}` "colors" the keys — but unfortunately the color is always gray. How change that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `showkeys` uses following code

```
\let\SK@refcolor\relax
\let\SK@labelcolor\relax
\DeclareOption{color}{\AtEndOfPackage{%
  \RequirePackage{color}%
  \definecolor{refkey}{gray}{.75}%
  \definecolor{labelkey}{gray}{.75}%
  \def\SK@refcolor{\color{refkey}}%
  \def\SK@labelcolor{\color{labelkey}}}}
```

in order to set the colour. `refkey` and `labelkey` are both set to a light gray 'colour'. It is sufficient to use a different definition of the `refkey` and `labelkey` colours.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[color]{showkeys}

\definecolor{refkey}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{labelkey}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\begin{document}
\section{My nice section}\label{foosection}


In \ref{foosection} we saw that\dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! That's what other posts here and elsewhere seem never to have gotten around to showing explicitly.

Comment: @murray: Sometimes (or very often? ;-)) it's necessary to dive into the `.sty` file ;-)

Comment: Now I need to figure out what *named* colors are available.  I'm using pdflatex from TeXShop's menu system and haven't a clue what driver is being used. Or is there some other way to find out?

Comment: @murray: See the `xcolor` documentation: There's a lot of information which colour names are available. You can name your colours of course yourself as you like

Comment: Will using package `xcolor` cause any difficulty in that `usepackage[color]{showkeys}` already automatically causes package `color` to be loaded?

Comment: @murray: No, you should load it after `showkeys` however. There will be warning about `incompatible` color definition, but using `\makeatletter
\def\SK@refcolor{\color{Aquamarine}}
\makeatother` should work, for example.